# What happens if I forget to water seedlings?

Tags: seeds, seedlings, seed-saving

Do my seedlings continue thriving by watering, if they were placed in a dry pot for a day or two without any water?

This question may have a relation to "[How do you water tiny seedlings](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/3083/1106)".

1st Edit: put image below.
[image: 1st]
[image: 2nd]
[image: 3rd]

They are sour oranges!

2nd Edit: Nothing happen, after 2 or 3 weeks observation they are healthy, some of them have leaves.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on every factor that you haven't included, species of seedling, humidity, how large of container and what material is it made from... How hot is it? What substrate are they planted in...

For instance: In the desert in the summer, most seedlings will wilt in a nursery flat if not watered continually, but in a coastal area during the spring you may only have to water some types of seedlings once or twice a week.

Comment: they are sour orange seeds, they are for a month in a small chocolate container, I keep them wet, lately they germinate, I try to put their image in my question. thank you.

Comment: I would buy some commercial citrus mix, keep them moist, but not wet until there first true leaves appear, then cut back a little bit.